# How to deal with promises in computed properties

Tags: ember-data

I'm wondering how should I deal with async belongsTo into computed properties of my models. Consider the following models :

```js
App.Invoice = DS.Model.extend()


App.Group = DS.Model.extend
  invoice: DS.belongsTo('group', {async: true}) 

App.Quotation = DS.Model.extend
  group: DS.belongsTo('group', {async: true}) 

  hasGroupInvoice: (->
     // if @get('group.invoice') ?
  ).property('group.invoice')
```

Here's my problem: As long as `quotation.group` and `group.invoice` are async belongsTo I don't know how to do.

I would like my computed property to returns `true` if `@get('group.invoice')` exist otherwise it should returns `false`

Thanks